# Interpret the skewness in R

Tags: skewness, histogram

I have a `skewness(x)`  equal to `[1] 0.51308`. Does this mean the graph is positively skewed or it is said to be symmetric?

My graph actually looks like that:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's insufficient information here to understand this distribution well. The skewness calculation is what it is, but it paints an incomplete picture. It's very possible that the data is zero-inflated, with the positive values reasonably symmetric. A more finely-resolved histogram and more information about the data would help understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

The value you have obtained is called the [sample skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness) (though this can be defined by a few different estimators).  It is a positive number, so you have *positive skewness* in your sample and your graph of the histogram of that sample is positively skewed.  Typically we would use the sample skewness to try to make an inference about the true skewness in the underlying population.  In the present case the sample size and other aspects of the sample are not clear from your density histogram, so this is not possible here.

Comment: There being different estimators is only part of the story. There are many measures of skewness other than the moment-based measure. It's perhaps common now for statistical people to regard the moment-based skewness as the standard or default measure, but its virtues are often overstated and its limitations often understated.

Answer (score 0):

*Positive skewness* tells us that the `mean` of the data values is larger than the `median`(i.e., the data distribution is *right-skewed*). Your graph is certainly positively skewed  from both the looks of the visualization and the value of the `skewness parameter`. The farther the `Skewness parameter` is from `0`, the more the data is *skewed* (in a *positive* or *negative* sense depending on the sign of the `skewness parameter`).

To comment properly on `Kurtosis`, you might want to consider checking the formula being used in the library imported by you to evaluate `Kurtosis`. Check for the presence of a `- 3` at the end of the formula.

If it does have a `- 3` at the end, then the *standard normal* distribution has a `kurtosis` of `0` (*Mesokurtic*) and by this definition, positive kurtosis (*Leptokurtic*) indicates a "*heavy-tailed*" distribution and `negative kurtosis` (*Platykurtic*) indicates a "*light-tailed*" distribution. `Kurtosis = 2` means *Leptokurtic* in this case.

If not, then the *standard normal* distribution has a `kurtosis` of `3`. So, `Kurtosis = 2` implies `Platykurtic` in this case.

The definition without `- 3` at the end is standard but it doesn't hurt to check to be sure.

Comment: Thanks,  what about kurtosis equal 2. Is it platykurtic  right?

Comment: @learningbtw I've updated the answer. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: @tpetzoldt agreed

Comment: The opening definition of skewness is incorrect, or at least not general. It's perfectly possible for the mean to equal the median yet for a distribution to be positively skewed in the sense of being asymmetric and having a longer or fatter tail of high values. 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 is a trivial example, and there are many skewed binomial distributions with integer means equal to medians.

Comment: Positive skew means that whatever you use to measure skewness is positive, which is not circular, as specify the measure, and see how it works.  If the measure is (mean - median) / SD for example, then the definition is satisfied, whereas if the measure is something else, e.g. the moment-based measure, it may not be for distributions with mean = median.